# can a ftp domain be changed from using ip to domain name like domain.com?

Tags: server, ftp, ip

so I have set a ftp on Ubuntu server using VMbox and I can access it from host(windows) browser by ftp://ip but can I using domain name like ftp://domain.com?
and how to do it?
my version Ubuntu server is 18.04.3 and for ftp is vsftpd

Padoru.

Answer (score 1):

To use `domain.com` instead of the IP, the FTP client resolves the name to an IP address.

#### Simple case

If "I" means "me alone", edit the `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` on Unix, `c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows) on the PC you use for the FTP **client** and add the IP address to which you add the name(s) you want.

#### Otherwise

If "I" means "any random user",  you use DNS name resolution. "domain.com" must be known everywhere and point to your address. So you have to register the name (if available) at a registrar (this entails a price, around $15/year for common names and TLDs) and then associate this name with your IP(*). After a few hours, all the internet will relate "domain.com" to your IP address.

(*) assuming the IP is public, not in the range `10.*.*.*` or `192.168.*.*`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to purchase a domain name and use a service like Hurricane Electric's Hosted DNS if your IP changes as their service allows for easy configuration using `ddclient`. If your IP doesn't change and you have a static IP you can use just the domain name and forward it to your IP using the DNS settings from wherever you purchase the domain i.e GoDaddy or similiar.

Free Hosted DNS https://dns.he.net/

Free domain names from https://www.freenom.com/en/freeandpaiddomains.html

Comment: can it using internal connection instead of internet? like using host-only adapter? thank you :)

Comment: No unfortunately not, you would need to bridge adapters and expose the machine to the router to have it addressable by other machines. I.e use bridged networking instead of host only or nat.